# printing logical sequence in python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements, sequence

My program reads two numbers X and Y (X < Y). After this, it show a sequence of 1 to Y, passing to the next line to each X numbers.

My code:

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

while count < (y//x):
    print('{} {} {}'.format(a, b, c))
    a += d
    b += d
    c += d
    count += 1
```

Sample input:

```
3 99
```

Output I want:  *each sequence must be printed in one line, with a blank space between each number, like the following example*

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
.....
....
97 98 99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use range to generate a list of `y` numbers, you can then iterate over this in `x` chunks

```py
def print_lines(x, y):
   nums = list(range(y))
   for i in nums[::x]:
      print(" ".join([str(num + 1) for num in nums[i:i + x]]))

print_lines(3, 99)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two loops, the code will look like the following:

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
count = 0

while count < (y//x):
    start = count*x + 1
    end = (count + 1) * x + 1
    for i in range(start,end,1):
        print(i,end=" ")
    print("")
    count+=1
```

Comment: Is it an Online Judge problem @MohammadShakib?

Comment: Yes [Problem link](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1145)

Comment: Then you should solve it by yourself. I can help you understand why an online judge gives the verdict "Presentation Error".

"Presentation Error" means you are printing some extra space or new line in your solution. Now try to find the problem by yourself and fix it.